#  How do I solve level 11 on Mad difficulty?

Tags: dr-laser

I'm playing the Dr. Laser game for Android and I'm stuck for quite a while now on level 11 (difficulty=Mad).

Can anyone provide a hint regarding the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a hint from the game's author about this level and it helped me solve it.

Here it is:

[image]

Comment: very nice ascii, you got me started on this game because of your question but got stuck on level 9 on Mad

Comment: Thank you, Blem! Mad level 9 is also very hard and in order to solve it I used the hint available here: http://androidforums.com/android-games/342983-free-puzzle-game-dr-laser.html (see second post by Dr. Laser). Good luck!